# Labelled and Unlabelled

Tags: combinatorics

In combinatorics, what is the difference between labelled and unlabelled families?

[Here](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/comb/ch2s.pdf) on question five, it found that there are 256 labelled families of subsets of a $3-$set and $20$ unlabelled families. I have no idea what labelled and unlabelled are.

The book doesn't give a formal definition, instead it gives examples which aren't clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A labeled finite set $S$ is a set together with a bijective function $S\to [|S|]$. Deciding when two of these sets are the same depends on the context. For example, we would say that two labeled graphs are the same if there is an isomorphism between them preserving the labeling of the vertices (the bijective function mentioned above). In the context of your question it seems that the labeling on the family arises from a labeling of the whole set, so the labeling of the whole set would restrict to a function on the subsets in the family. In this case two labeled families are the same if they contain the same sets. For the unlabeled version of the problem, two families would be considered the same if there is a bijection from the whole set to itself inducing a bijections between the sets in the two families.

Comment: But how does a bijection translate into having 256 labelled families of subsets of a $3-$ set.

Comment: @Robben there are 8 subsets of the set and hence $2^8=256$ sets of subsets. The more interesting question in this case is what an unlabeled family is.

Comment: Your edit is much better, thank you! And yes, that is the more interesting question. Why is it 20?

Comment: I'm not sure about the best way to do the calculation, but to see why there are fewer for example $\{\{a,b\},\{a\}\}$ would be considered the same as $\{\{b,c\},\{c\}\}$ because there is a bijection sending one to the other.

Comment: So ${a,b,c}$ counts as one subset, right? And would $\{\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$ be considered a subset? So it's pretty much how many different ways are there to put ${a,b,c},{a,b},{b,c},{a,c},{a},{b},{c}} as a subset?

Comment: That's how you get the 256, by choosing sets consisting of those subsets.

Comment: Whoa. So $\{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}$ are all considered to be the same when it's unlabelled?

Comment: You have to consider the entire family of sets. If each is the only set in the family, then the families are all the same. If there are two of those sets in a single family though, then the two one element sets are not identified.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by the entire family of sets. By that do you mean, the empty set, 1-set, 2-set and 3-set?

Comment: In $\{\{a,b\},\{a\},\{b\}\}$ for example there are two 1 sets that would remain distinct in the unlabeled context.

Comment: My last question, what will make the 1-set the same then under unlabelled?

Comment: $\{\{a\}\}$ and $\{\{b\}\}$ for example would be the same. I would always be going back to the definition of when two families are the same.